# How to dynamically add CORS sites to Google Cloud App Engine Node API

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cors

I am new to API deployment.

I have a Node Express API that has CORS enabled in the root app.js, for the API and a socket.io implementation:

```
var app = express();
app.use(cors({
   origin : ["http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081"],
   credentials: true
}))
```

and

```
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, { 
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081"],
        credentials: true,
        methods: ["GET"]
    }
});
```

I will set up a sales website that allows a customer to pay for a license to use the API with their site, i.e. `https://www.customersite.com`

**My question is how can I dynamically add the customer's website (say after they submit a form from another site) to the CORS list?** Ideally it would be via an API call. The only option which I can think of (that is not automated) is to manually maintain a global js file (i.e. `config.js`) with the cors list from within the Google platform using the file explorer / editor, and to iterate over it as an array similar to `process.env.customerList`. This will not work for me as I need to have this step happen automatically.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Seems I was confused about how I should tackle this problem, it has nothing to do with the platform of deployment. Essentially it seems the whitelisted origins should be stored in a database and accessed every time an API request is made, as middleware. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin

Comment: Could you post your solution so that it could help other community members when they view this or have similar issue?

Comment: Haven't finished implementation yet, will do once I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Use a process manager like pm2 to 'reload' the API gracefully with close to no downtime.

PM2 reloads can be triggered programmatically. I made a PUT endpoint for modifying CORS list `/cors/modify` that sent a programmatic pm2 message when a successful modification was done.

**Note**: on Windows OS must use programmatic messaging:

```
pm2.list(function(err, list) {
    pm2.sendDataToProcessId(list[0].pm2_env.pm_id, 
        {
            type : 'process:msg',
            data : {
                msg : 'shutdown'
            },
            topic: true
        },
        function(err, res) {
            console.log(err);
            pm2.disconnect();   // Disconnects from PM2
        }
    );
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        pm2.disconnect();   // Disconnects from PM2
    }
});
```

which can then be caught with

```
process.on('message', async function(msg) {
    if (msg == "shutdown" || msg.data.msg == 'shutdown') {
        console.log("Disconnecting from DB...");
        mongoose.disconnect((e => {
            if (e) {
                process.exit(1)
            } else {
                console.log("Mongoose connection removed");
                httpServer.close((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                        process.exit(1)
                    }
                    process.exit(0);
                })
            }
        }));
    }
});
```